# How to deal with not existing values using JSON_EXTRACT?

Tags: mysql, mysql-json

I have a list ob objects. Each object contains several properties. Now I want to make a `SELECT` statement that gives me a list of a single property values. The simplified list look like this:

```
[
    [
        {
            "day": "2021-10-01",
            "entries": [
                {
                    "name": "Start of competition",
                    "startTimeDelta": "08:30:00"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "day": "2021-10-02",
            "entries": [
                {
                    "name": "Start of competition",
                    "startTimeDelta": "03:30:00"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "day": "2021-10-03",
            "entries": [
                {
                    "name": "Start of competition"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
]
```

The working `SELECT` is now

```
SELECT
    JSON_EXTRACT(column, '$.days[*].entries[0].startTimeDelta') AS list
FROM table
```

The returned result is

```
[
    "08:30:00",
    "03:30:00"
]
```

But what I want to get (and also have expected) is

```
[
    "08:30:00",
    "03:30:00",
    null
]
```

What can I do or how can I change the `SELECT` statement so that I also get `NULL` values in the list?

Comment: @Akina this is a very simplified version of my passed object. So I removed content for StackOverflow and missed that comma.

Comment: This would be so much easier if you did not use JSON, but used normal rows and columns. Then your `startTimeDelta` column would be NULL where the value is missing. Using JSON when you really need data structured relationally forces you into the [Inner-Platform Effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner-platform_effect) antipattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
SELECT startTimeDelta
FROM test
CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE(val,
                      '$[*][*].entries[*]' COLUMNS (startTimeDelta TIME PATH '$.startTimeDelta')) jsontable
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=491f0f978d200a8a8522e3200509460e

---

> Do you also have a working idea for MySQL< 8? – Lars
>
> What is max amount of objects in the array on the 2nd level? – Akina
>
> Well it's usually less than 10 – Lars

```sql
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(val, CONCAT('$[0][', num, '].entries[0].startTimeDelta')) startTimeDelta
FROM test
-- up to 4 - increase if needed
CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 num UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3) nums
WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(val, CONCAT('$[0][', num, '].entries[0]')) IS NOT NULL;
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xnCCSTGQXevcpfPH1GAbUo/0

Comment: that looks very smart. Thank you. Unfortunately, it doesn't work on MySQL 5.7 and I have no chance to upgrade. Do you also have a working idea for MySQL< 8?

Comment: @Lars *it doesn't work on MySQL 5.7* Always provide precise version if it is not actual... *Do you also have a working idea for MySQL< 8?* It is possible, but it will be monstruous.  The structure has 3 levels of nested arrays. Do we can refer to `'$[0].[*].entries[0].startTimeDelta'` always?

Comment: the missing MySQL version was a mistake, indeed. The JSON path `'$[0].[*].entries[0].startTimeDelta'` is always fix.

Comment: @Lars What is max amount of objects in the array on the 2nd level?

Comment: Well it's usually less than 10